# Color scheme in questions lists needs some help

Tags: feature-request, design

The color contrast here (MetaSF /questions) is a bit difficult.  Fine on the home page, but white and yellow against light gray isn't enough of a contrast.  Talking about the vote / answer boxes.

**EDIT:**

Ok, the gray boxes are gone but can something be done about the yellow on the number of answers when one's been accepted?  Keep it black or something to keep in line with the toned down scheme of meta, but the yellow doesn't have enough contrast.

Comment: Ack. I can't read it either.

Comment: +1  Also, I've always had trouble with the color for links on SF.  I almost miss them unless hit with onMouseOver.  Even worse when they're nested inside a <PRE>.

Answer (score 5):

You're right, yellow-on-white is not a good choice for much of anything.