# Answered color styling on Meta

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Color scheme in questions lists needs some help](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/464/color-scheme-in-questions-lists-needs-some-help)

This is a meta-meta bug report: number of answers in an "accepted" box is pretty much unreadable on Meta SF:

[image: Question with an accepted answer]

Would be great if color could be changed to something more palatable. For the record, I don't have color blindness.

Comment: @Iain : Yes, a full duplicate, can be merged with the original (to preserve the illustration), provided the original is bumped up )) for eventual (`sigh`...) resolution