# The Server Fault logo has some alignment issues

Tags: bug, design

When looking at the [Server Fault logo in this SVG file](http://cdn.sstatic.net/serverfault/img/sprites.svg?v=244ec30bccbd), it looks like this (zoomed):

[image]

You can see that the blocks in the third column are some "pixels" down in Y compared to the blocks in the other two columns.

(The meta icon seems to have the same behaviour)

To me this looks like a bug.

Probably I'm overly nit-picky, I just wanted to notify about this here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, it confirmed by looking of *source code* of svg file. The xml below was grabbed from [svg file](http://cdn.sstatic.net/serverfault/img/sprites.svg?v=244ec30bccbd) especially on SF logo parts.

```
        <g>
            <rect x="-176.6" y="-178.1" fill="#A7A8AB" width="22" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-176.6" y="-171" fill="#808284" width="22" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-176.6" y="-164.4" fill="#59595B" width="22" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-176.6" y="-185.1" fill="#D1D2D4" width="22" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-176.6" y="-157.3" fill="#221F1F" width="22" height="4.4"/>
        </g>
            <rect x="-152" y="-178.1" fill="#982224" width="9.4" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-152" y="-171" fill="#630F16" width="9.4" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-152" y="-164.4" fill="#2B1315" width="9.4" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-152" y="-185.1" fill="#E7282D" width="9.4" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-152" y="-157.3" fill="#221F1F" width="9.4" height="4.4"/>
        <g>
            <rect x="-140.1" y="-177.9" fill="#A7A8AB" width="9.4" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-140.1" y="-170.8" fill="#808284" width="9.4" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-140.1" y="-164.2" fill="#59595B" width="9.4" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-140.1" y="-184.9" fill="#D1D2D4" width="9.4" height="4.4"/>
            <rect x="-140.1" y="-157.1" fill="#221F1F" width="9.4" height="4.4"/>
        </g>
```

SF logo consists of 5 x 3 rectangular and can be grouped per "column". You can notice that the third group has different **y** properties compared with other groups. The differences of y position is **0.2 pixel**.