# Favorites page "answers" text spilling outside its box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I'm not sure how this should look, but I'm fairly sure that it shouldn't look like [this](https://serverfault.com/users/17794/dsolimano?tab=favorites).

[image]

Comment: Can you post this as an answer to http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7995/site-design-update-is-now-live? This way, @jin who appears to be responsible for the layout get pinged about it automatically (although this might also be the result of the new user profile page...).

Comment: @Sven, done, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Site design update is now live](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7995/site-design-update-is-now-live)