# New design readability - all comments are ignored

Tags: discussion, design

So, the most upvoted answer on [Site design update is now live](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7995/site-design-update-is-now-live) is about the poor choice of colors, making the new design unreadable. I wonder why, even though there's a good buy-in and support for this problem, there have been no comments. Not even a "live with it and shut up".

Kind of makes you wonder if anyone cares about what the users think.

EDIT: Just to keep things clear, this post is not about the site readability issue, it's about the fact that there has been no response to the complaint

Comment: [This](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8054/abrupt-change-in-moderation-staff#comment17368_8054).

Comment: @AndréDaniel nailed it :)

Answer (score -4):

You haven't given very good feedback on your complaint. You'll need to be way more specific if you want anyone to do anything about it.

For example, I do not have any issues at all reading anything on the site. So clearly whatever is causing you to have difficulties is not something that everyone is suffering.

If it's something that is causing specific difficulty for you, but not the wider community, then I suggest you come up with a far more detailed report about the issues that you're having.

Comment: Clearly? So why are there multiple complaints about the same thing in http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7995/site-design-update-is-now-live and so many upvotes on all of them? All those answers have provided the same comment - the new fonts are too light, that hurts readability, because contrast goes down. Previously, the fonts were a darker blue, and reading was much easier.

Comment: @dynasny: I do completely agree both with your points about the readability issues as well as the lack of official comment on the matter, but perhaps it would be beneficial to also update the title of this post to reflect the fact it's questioning the lack of comment rather than the readability as already addressed?

Comment: @BE77Y Already put that in an edit, but I've also changed the title, just in case

Comment: Upvoted because, while I'm not a fan of the design's heavy use of white space and I find it much more unpleasant, I don't want to say "I don't like this!" without having some more objective reasons and possible alternatives.