# SF layout / Answer coloring

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

I just wanted to report a small bug in the layout, in the answer section.

On IE, FireFox & Chrome I see my profile that way (note the answers how it look like (no box)):

[image]

On my blackberry I see it that way (note the answers now, green box) :

[image]

I really prefer how the BB display it personally, can we fix it to display it all green for all the major browser ?

Thanks

Comment: I [reported this earlier when the design went live](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/8027/126632) and was utterly ignored.

Comment: @MichaelHampton oh ok :|  Atleast then it show them it's a bug, not a feature request. unless they can explain to me how they draw a green box by error.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - raised on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260500/how-often-do-developers-monitor-site-specific-metas-for-bugs