# Questions with accepted answers should stand out more

Tags: feature-request, design, color

Questions with accepted answers are *less* emphasized than those without. Is this intentional, and if so is there a reason for this? SO has a green background so perhaps I'm just biased by that, but it seems like these should be visually labelled somehow.

[image: screenshot]

On a related note, the colours on the question list do show a difference, but the colours used are unnecessarily difficult to tell apart, as both are green:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

When the UI got updated in the past, it was reported as a bug and never fixed.

A side note on mobile the UI is the same for all site, as such the color are better suited for question with accepted answer

See there for example; https://meta.serverfault.com/a/8027/126632

A report I did in the past too; [SF layout / Answer coloring](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8209/sf-layout-answer-coloring)