# Server Fault SE style format improvement

Tags: discussion, support, design

I added few tags in Favorite tag list. Whenever I scrolling down the questions on this site, i found myself a bit trouble to see Favorite tagged questions. I'm not saying I can't see but not in comfort way like other sites.

[image]

The questions marked as accepted answer is even more difficult to see. It is a request if it is possible to change, it will be good for the users using this site.

Comment: My theory is the one that choosen the color theme in the past was colourblind

Comment: I agree that the color contrast is not that good. That said, [the last time a Q&A site got custom design was 2016-10-06.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6140766#6140766), so I won't give a high expectation to this...

Comment: @AndrewT. it was even reported to Jin in 2015, for the answer part, but totally ignored. There http://meta.serverfault.com/a/8027/126632

Comment: @yagmoth555 Okay so this is already discussed still I hope in future, this point will consider.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I have to repeat for the accepted answer and not accepted ones, actually very confusing. So the box and has **dark green outline** is the **accepted** one and _only box_ is **not accepted** and _without box_, **no answer**.

Comment: @daisy I agree with you, my point was more we (as the SF community) got ignored for that design, but I like to see the point comingback, as  maybe someday it will change if we keep tàking about it