# Visual bug with displaing badges

Tags: bug, status-completed

See picture for details:

[image]

My browser if FF v61.0.1

Comment: I can repro on my FF too.

Comment: This affects multiple sites. This has also been asked recently on main META: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314038/badge-icons-partially-hidden-on-some-sites-with-the-new-design

Comment: I'm seeing this on user cards too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed and will go out in the next build. Thanks for pointing it out!